# ObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13115) error in pandas dataframe; issues in indexing a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have imported data from a csv file and the data looks like this :

```
    user_id movie_id    rating  ts  name    year
0   196 242 3   881250949   Kolya (1996)    24-Jan-1997
1   63  242 3   875747190   Kolya (1996)    24-Jan-1997
2   226 242 5   883888671   Kolya (1996)    24-Jan-1997
3   154 242 3   879138235   Kolya (1996)    24-Jan-1997
4   306 242 5   876503793   Kolya (1996)    24-Jan-1997
5   296 242 4   884196057   Kolya (1996)    24-Jan-1997
6   34  242 5   888601628   Kolya (1996)    24-Jan-1997
```

My code :

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin,delimiter='\t)
```

I am trying to index a column using `df['rating']`, and its giving me the above error. 
I have also tried `df.loc[:,'rating']` which is giving me the error of

> the label [rating] is not in the [columns]'

When I try to get the column names using `print(df.column.values)`, I get the error of

> return object.**getattribute**(self, name) AttributeError: 'DataFrame'
>   object has no attribute 'column'

I am not sure, how to proceed from here, Any input is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: your file probably doesn't have all tabs.  check `df.columns` and see if you have any unexpected column names.  using `strip` may fix it.  `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`

Comment: after doing the str. strip. df.columns gives me this Index([u'Unnamed: 0  user_id  movie_id  rating         ts  \'], dtype='object') .

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
df.set_index('rating', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the parsing. Most plausible scenario is that your input is not really tab-separated (probably multiple spaces instead of tabs).

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin, sep=' +')
print (df.columns)
```